# Trying to pass a string back from a function in PowerShell

Tags: function, powershell, byref

```
function ExtractLocations([ref]$lp_Locations) {
    $lp_Locations.Value = "A STRING VALUE"

    return 0
}

...   

$Locations = ""
if (@(ExtractLocations([ref]$Locations)) -ne 0) {
    RecordErrorThenExit
}
```

`$Locations` always ends up as a blank string.

Comment: The symptom you describe is inconsistent with the sample code, which should work, but note that there' s no good reason to use `@(...)`, and that the function call should use a space after the function name to make it clearer that this is not a method call, and that the only reason `(...)` is required is to enclose expression `[ref] $Locations` in argument mode. Also, in PowerShell you typically output _data_, not _status codes_; that is, you'd typically return the _string_, and use `Write-Error` or `throw` to indicate failure.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what @mklemen0 said, to set the value, you need not to do it like `$Variable.Value = 'Something'` , its just `$Variable = 'Something'`

With the `@()` expression, you are converting the output to an array which is not what you need here. Declaring functions similar to methods in c# is not suggested in PowerShell. You could do it like below.

```
function ExtractLocations{
    Param([ref]$lp_Locations)
    $lp_Locations = "A STRING VALUE"

    return 0
}

ExtractLocations -lp_Locations ([ref]$Locations)
```

Comment: Tried that but still not working :    function ExtractLocations 
{
    Param([ref]$lp_Locations)

    $lp_Locations = "String Value"

    return 0
}

....

    $Locations = ""
    if ((ExtractLocations -lp_Locations ([ref]$Locations)) -ne 0){RecordErrorThenExit}

Answer (score 0):

Could not get it working with parameters no matter what I tried so returned the value as a string and that works:

function ExtractLocations 
{
....
    return $lp_Locations
}

$Locations = ExtractLocations
write "MODIFY $TABLE TO REORGANIZE WITH LOCATION = ($($Locations.value)) \p\g" | sql $SQLFLAGS $TARGETDB